# How can I using a std::barrier get the other threads to return if one thread fails?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

In my program I need to start 2 pieces of external hardware.
This is somewhat time consuming and I therefore want to run it in separate threads.
The start-up has two parts. The second part, `hardwareTask2()`, must be performed ca. simultaneously on both threads.
I therefore want to use a `std::barrier` to synchronize before calling this method.
However, the first part of the start-up, `hardwareTask1()` may fail.
If it fails on either thread I want both threads to return.
How do I achieve this?
Using `std::barrier::arrive_and_drop()` below I have managed to at least get the other thread to finish (not wait indefinitely at the barrier).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <barrier>

bool hardwareTask1(unsigned int id) {
    srand(id);
    int r = rand() % 10;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(r));
    return true;
}

// must be called ca. simultaneously:
void hardwareTask2() {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
}

void startHardware(unsigned int id, std::barrier<>& b) {
    bool ok = hardwareTask1(id);
    // Simulate that the above function failed for the first thread:
    if (id == 1) {
        ok = false;
    }
    if (!ok) {
        b.arrive_and_drop();
        return;
    }
    std::cerr << id << ": finished task1\n";
    b.arrive_and_wait();
    std::cerr << id << ": after barrier\n";

    hardwareTask2();
}

int main()
{
    std::barrier<> b(2);
    std::thread t1(&startHardware, 1, std::ref(b));
    std::thread t2(&startHardware, 2, std::ref(b));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    std::cerr << "Both threads have finished.\n";
    int k;
    std::cin >> k;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered `std::future`? You don't have to return anything, but at least you get an exception if either call fails. Why did you decide the tool (`std::barrier`) to use already?

Comment: Why not pair the barrier with an `std::atomic_uint` initialized with the same value?  If the first stage succeeds decrement the atomic before calling `arrive_and_wait` then, after `arrive_and_wait` returns, continue if the atomic is zero otherwise return immediately.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you. So this std::atomic_uint would be passed by reference to both threads? If so could I not pass a std::atomic<bool>& terminated to both threads? If thread 1 fails it sets this to true. Before hardwareTask2 thread 2 checks this value and determines if it should return immediately or call  hardwareTask2.

Comment: @Andy Sure.  If the use-case is simple enough an atomic bool (or even [`std::atomic_flag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag)) should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Like @UlrichEckhardt mentioned in his comment, you can use a `std::future`, `std::promise` pair to do the synchronization. Small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <random>
#include <thread>

void hardwareTask1(std::promise<bool> p)
{
    std::cout << "HW 1: First part\n";
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(1, 10);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(distrib(gen)));

    int res = distrib(gen);
    if (res > 5) {
        p.set_value(true);
        std::cout << "HW 1: Second part\n";
    }
    else {
        p.set_value(false);
        std::cout << "HW 1: First part failed - abort\n";
    }
}

void hardwareTask2(std::future<bool> f)
{
    std::cout << "HW 2: First part\n";
    if (f.get())
        std::cout << "HW 2: Second part\n";
    else
        std::cout << "HW 2: HW 1 failed - abort\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::promise<bool> p;
    std::thread t2(&hardwareTask2, p.get_future());
    std::thread t1(&hardwareTask1, std::move(p));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```